# Trying to find a way to get the row and column names of csv in html/js by using d3 , any other ways?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

```
 <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]"    onchange="handleFileSelect()" />
```

This is my input for the file which is a csv , I want to find a way to parse the row and col names as variables and use them in another script so far I have this 3
   script src="d3.min.js?v=3.2.8">

```
    <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">                          
        d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {                                
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);                         

            var container = d3.select("body")                               
                .append("table")                                            

                .selectAll("tr")                                            
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()                                
                    .append("tr")                                           

              .selectAll("td")                                        
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()                
                    .append("td")                                           
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });                       
        });
```

Is there any other way to do do it or do I have to port the container and the row and columns into the new script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I want to find a way to parse the row and col names as variables"

There is no *row* names in a CSV, only column (header) names.

If I correctly understand your question, you want to get the *column names*, which are the headers in a CSV. What you're using right now, `csv.parseRows`, won't work, because it will return *every*  row as an array. So, to get the columns names (again, if I correctly understand what you want), the solution is simple:

When you load a CSV with `d3.csv`, D3 v4.x automatically creates an array property named `columns`, which contains the header names, in the input order.

So, if your CSV is something like:

```
foo,bar,baz
12,42,31
11,23,56
//etc...
```

When you load it in a variable named `data`, for instance, `data.columns` will be an array with the headers names:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Check this snippet (I'm using `<pre>` to write the data, because I can't load an external CSV in S.O. snippets):

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());
console.log(data.columns);
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">
Device Name,Platform,OS Version,Portrait Width,Landscape Width,Release Date
Acer Iconia Tab A1-810,Android,4.2.2,768,1024,2013-05
Acer Iconia Tab A100,Android,4.0.3,800,1280,2011-04
Acer Iconia Tab A101,Android,3.2.1,600,1024,2011-05
Acer Iconia Tab A200,Android,4.0.3,800,1280,2012-01
Acer Iconia Tab A500,Android,4.0.3,648,1280,2011-04
Acer Iconia Tab A501,Android,3.2,800,1280,2011-04
ACER Liquid E2,Android,4.2.1,360,640,2013-05
</pre>
```